# R package ape: extract the first two nucleotide in the codon

Tags: r, bioinformatics, r-package

I have a fasta file containing a DNA seq.
I would like to delete the 3rd nucleotide in each codon.
I thought I can select the first 2 nucleotide in a subsetting step.

I work in R, using the ape and seqinr packages

```
>read.dna("test3", format="fasta")-> test3
>test3
1 DNA sequences in binary format stored in a matrix.

All sequences of same length: 888 

Labels: XX_00004 

Base composition:
    a     c     g     t 
0.223 0.222 0.293 0.262
```

Using the function `seq` I can select the first, second, and third nucleotide singularly in each codon, but I cannot select first & second.

```
>test3[seq(1, length(test3), by = 3)]
1 DNA sequence in binary format stored in a vector.

Sequence length: 296 

Base composition:
    a     c     g     t 
0.256 0.249 0.374 0.121
>test3[seq(1:2, length(test3), by = 3)]
Error in seq.default(1:2, length(test3), by = 3) : 
  'from' must be of length 1

> test3[seq(from=1, to=2, length(test3), by = 3)]
Error in seq.default(from = 1, to = 2, length(test3), by = 3) : 
  too many arguments
```

Any suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the first and second by excluding the third:

```
test3[-seq(3, length(test3), by = 3)]
```

Comment: Sorry for asking one more question. But do you know how to replace it with a gap?

Comment: sorry no. I tried "test3[seq(3, length(test3), by = 3)]<-'-'", but that doesn't work. I don't really use that package much.